# Whether is it necessary to add tealium jquery codes into our website?

Tags: google-analytics, tealium

I want to integrate google analytics with tealium.
I added google analytics from tags tab and applied my tracking id in the tracking field. Also added some variables. 
While publishing I had some jquery codes which were generated from tealium code center.
Whether I have to add those codes in my website? 
Is it necessary?
Where can I see the output whether its working properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery itself should not be required to get Google Analytics running on your site (assuming an out-of-the-box implementation). I suspect that any of that logic is related to something else.

The easiest non-technical way to validate that Google Analytics is running correctly on your site is to check the Real-time reports of your GA property while you're browsing it (assuming you've published your Tealium property to the appropriate environment) and check to see if a visitor (you) shows up.

From a technical perspective, open a browser and navigate to one of your pages. Open your developer tools (assuming Chrome, use Ctrl + Shift + J) and click on the Network tab at the top. In the filter, type "collect" without the quotes and refresh the page. If you've correctly implemented GA on the page, you'll see a network request show up in the box below the filter. If you select it, under Headers on the right, there should be a section for General and the Request URL will start with https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect. This is the pageview tracking request sent to Google Analytics, so if you see it, it's working.